# how to send base64 string in android?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am trying to make hydrid application in which there is a  "button"  on `HTML` page .whenever I click on that button i want to call android code function **(which is working fine when I called `test` function from javascript)** .Now I want to capture image on button click
I take help from below url.
[Capture Image from Camera and Display in Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity)
I do like this
package com.example.myapp.myapplication;

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    private static final int MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        // webView.loadUrl("http://1.5.20.97:3671");
        webView.loadUrl("http://15.16.74.160:6019");
        JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "JSInterface");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
          //  Log.d("My map",photo,"");
        }
    }

    public void checkTest(){
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE);
        } else {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}


class JavaScriptInterface {
    private MainActivity activity;


    public JavaScriptInterface(MainActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void test() {
        this.activity.checkTest();
    }


    @JavascriptInterface
    public String bitMapToBase64()
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        //add support for jpg and more.
        bitMap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();

        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

        return encoded;
    }


}
```

I am getting import error
[image]

**I am trying to call a android function which open camera and capture image and return to javascript.**

on javascript I am calling function like this

```
console.log(window.JSInterface.test())
```

Comment: this is not an import error, that's the image you want to convert to base64

Comment: When you capture the image,onactivityresult you show your webview again and execute the javascript code to retrieve the image from android

Comment: You didn't have to delete your other post,  you could've opened an other thread .

Comment: undeleted the other post .accepted answer

Comment: `When you capture the image,onactivityresult you show your webview again and execute the javascript code to retrieve the image from android` ?? could you please modified my code

Comment: javascript part i will handle ..only issue to send the base64 string to javascript

Comment: I am working on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to go back to your `webView` when you capture the image from camera, change your `onActivityResult` method to this

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        if (webView != null)
           webView.loadUrl("http://125.16.74.160:30019");
    }
}
```

Also you should declare you `bitmap` as a global static variable like this

public static Bitmap photo;

Then `bitMapToBase64` become like this

```
@JavascriptInterface
public String bitMapToBase64()
{
  if (MainActivity.photo != null) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    //add support for jpg and more.
    MainActivity.photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();

    String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

    return encoded;
  }
  return "null image";
}
```

In the javascript side you check if bitMapToBase64 function has a return value different than "null image" you convert the base64 image to a blob or image object and show it in a div for example.

Here is an example how to convert your base64 string to an image object and append it to your body

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...';
document.body.appendChild(image);
```